# cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after event fired only once when place order? (CLOSED)

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer, installation, stock, ee-1.13.0.2

I have **observer** the stock item when order placed:

```
<global>
    <events>
                    ...
        <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_stock_item_save_after>
                    <class>mymodule/observer_stockItem</class>
                    <method>afterSaveStockItem</method>
                </mymodule_stock_item_save_after>
            </observers>
        </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

The code handle the **event**:

```
public function afterSaveStockItem($observer) {
    $productId = $observer->getEvent()->getItem()->getProductId();
    Mage::log($productId, null, "stockItemOrder.log");
}
```

I try place an order with two products, but the log out only one product id.

what is the problem? Could I have a bug in my magento install(ver. 1.13.0.2)?

> **Update:**
>   **After some check the stock event is not fired when order is created. So I marked my question to CLOSED, many thanks to everyone.**

Comment: Now it doesn't run that event when order placed at all.

Comment: the config.xml you have posted seems to have an error in it, the closing `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after` appears to be `mymodule_stock_item_save_commit_after`

Comment: Was that the only issue you where having?

Comment: No the issue is the cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after event not fired when order created. I closed this question, thanks for your support.

Comment: And you have the the shop working with stock status or is that disabled?

Comment: I overwrite model cataloginventory/stock for detect stock change

Answer (score 2):

I use a module that tracks stock movements, for all sales it uses the `checkout_submit_all_after` event.

Inside the Observer it uses this function:

```
public function checkoutAllSubmitAfter($observer)
{
    if ($observer->getEvent()->hasOrders()) {
        $orders = $observer->getEvent()->getOrders();
    } else {
        $orders = array($observer->getEvent()->getOrder());
    }
    $stockItems = array();
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            if ($orderItem->getQtyOrdered()) {
                $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                    ->loadByProduct($orderItem->getProductId());
                if (!isset($stockItems[$stockItem->getId()])) {
                    $stockItems[$stockItem->getId()] = array(
                        'item'   => $stockItem,
                        'orders' => array($order->getIncrementId()),
                    );
                } else {
                    $stockItems[$stockItem->getId()]['orders'][] = $order->getIncrementId();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modify this code and give it a whirl :)